# Show by a bijection that $S$, the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb Q$, is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

At first I thought something like:

"Define $g: S \to \Bbb N$ by,

given ($\frac{m_1}{n_1}$, $\frac{m_2}{n_2}$, ... , $\frac{m_k}{n_k}$) $\in S$, map this to $m_1n_1m_2n_2...m_kn_k \in \Bbb N$" might work, but negatives messed that up.

I tried other things with prime exponentiation, but it doesn't work either. Of course the codomain doesn't have to be $\Bbb N$ (e.g, could be $\Bbb Q$ or any other known countable set), but I'm not sure that would make it easier.

Comment: Hint: if you want to encode an n-tuple of positive integers, but don't know in advance how large n is going to be, you can use the injective map $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) \mapsto 2^{a_1} 3^{a_2} 5^{a_3} \cdots p_n^{a_n}$. Can you adapt this to your problem?

Comment: @HenrySwanson to be sure, that the mapping is injective follows directly from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic? Or is it a little more complicated than that?

Comment: Yep, it's a direct consequence of that. But now with $\Bbb Q$, you've got numerators and denominators, plus maybe a negative sign. There's many ways to handle this; what are your thoughts so far?

Comment: @HenrySwanson Well we need to have that the $ai's$ are positive integers, as the unique factorization into primes holds only in that case. I'm having trouble injecting the rationals into the positive integers. Pictorially ("zig-zag" argument) I see how it might be done (my book does something similar). But I'm not sure how (or whether) you can do it with a strict formula.

Comment: @HenrySwanson I think I've actually figured it out, though there might be a simpler way that I would be interested in. Map ($\frac{m_1}{n_1},...,\frac{m_k}{n_k}$) to $2^{q_1}3^{q_2}...p_n^{q_n}$ where $q_i$ is determined thus: for positive integers $m_i, n_i$ we have a string of ones whose length is determined by the integer value, separated by a $0$. E.g., $\frac{4}{3}$ = 11110111. For negative numbers, say $\frac{4}{-3}$ we use a string of $2$'s. So this $q_i$ will be $11110222$.